# Rust privacy rules - How to move a struct into a module without making it public while keeping it visible to the module it "came from"

Tags: rust

When I move a struct into a new module I am forced to make it public for it to be visible from the containing module (one level higher, "super" module). But I don't want it to be public, because I do not want the struct to be visible outside of the module it is destined for.

The reason I want to do this is to split a long file into multiple logical entities, each in separate files.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to expose something as public just for a crate or module.

In this case, the simplest solution is to make the struct public within the crate. Although, making it `pub(super)` also works.

```
pub(crate) struct ...
```

Further info: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/visibility-and-privacy.html

Answer (score 1):

> When I move a struct into a new module I am forced to make it public for it to be visible from the containing module (one level higher, "super" module).

First, as the other answer noted you don't have to mark the item as blanket `pub`, you can mark it as `pub(crate)`, `pub(super)`, or even `pub(in <path>)` to make it only visible across the crate or in submodules of the crate.

> But I don't want it to be public, because I do not want the struct to be visible outside of the module it is destined for.

But second, that an item is marked `pub` does not mean it's *externally* visible, to be externally visible it has to be exported *from the top-level of the crate* (the `lib.rs` file), either because it's there in the first place or by a `pub use` statement e.g.

```rust
mod foo {
    pub const BAR: u8 = 0;
}
use foo::BAR;
```

will allow the parent to use the `BAR` symbol, but it will not make the symbol externally visible, because it's just `use` (an "import") not `pub use` (a re-exporting import).

Comment: I used to think that I can "safely" mark private items as public as long as they are not reexported. But it's not quite the same as marking them as public in the current crate (or in whatever submodule). One of them is that, for types, a consumer of the library cannot *name* the type, but can still *use* it if that doesn't require naming it (which is pretty rare, but can happen).